# Extracting text from webpage, processing with Perl/Python, then rebuilding the page with links added

Tags: python, perl, nlp, html-parsing

I'm building a web app that processes the text in a web page, adds links to certain entities, then re-displays the page exactly as it was, but with some links added. My server-side code is in Perl and Python, and I'm currently using HTML::Parser to extract the text from a page. I can clean the markup, extract, and process the text without issue, but I want to display the original page exactly as it was, only with some links added to previously unlinked text.

I'm hoping to find out the best way to redisplay the exact same page with links added to certain words or phrases in the text. All of the original markup should be preserved exactly as it was before the text was extracted.

I've searched thoroughly, but I cannot find a precise solution to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pe[a]rl *and* Python? Surely one would eat (or choke on) the other!

Comment: i'm using Perl for the html parsing and cgi stuff and python to do the Natural Language Processing (mostly nltk modules)

Comment: So is the question *just* about serializing the DOM in Perl? (Why not as HTML again, as HTML represents the DOM entirely? The DOM only covers the textual aspects, even though it is often "embellished" in a live context just as JavaScript.)

Comment: Ok I rephrased the question. I had assumed that manipulating a DOM-type object would be the easiest way to reinsert processed text, but I'm open to any solution or guidance that will help me solve this specific issue.

Comment: I think this is one of rare cases where a RegEx on a raw HTML text may be worth considering

Comment: Why not store the original HTML along with a "selector" (XPath or entirely custom) to the element in question? XPath would need to be refined to add "text selection region", if that is indeed needed... replaying may be a little tricky if change A makes change B's "selector" invalid. Replaying backwards might help here.

Comment: @cho Well, remember "where" the original word/phase was ;-) Pass out/in the information as it is extracted or requests a modification.

Comment: @pst yes I know I need to remember the position/index of the original word. I'm just wondering the best way to do this.

Comment: @DVK that would work, but I think it could get really messy and inefficient.

Comment: @cho - inefficient - No. Messy - if you do it right, not necessarily, but definitely high risk of that. There is a reason for "Don't parse (x)HTML with RegEx" rant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do know that Python has a module for opening webpages, called urllib:

```
import urllib
url = 'https://www.google.com/'
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
print page.read()    
#page.read is the url's source code, so you would print the source  code here.
```

you could also save a new html file with python like this:

```
page = page.read()
file = open('url.html', 'w')
file.writelines(page)
file.close()
```

In between you could modify the html source. Keep in mind that the webpages will look silly if you don't figure out how to save the files the pages are using. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but I need something that stores the indexes(positions) of the tags so that the text can be re-inserted with the same markup. For example, if the original text was, "<span id="x">The president</span> said <b>yesterday</b> that he would <i>not</i> accept <span id = "y"> any new policy changes </span>." I would extract "The president said yesterday that he would not accept any new policy changes." Then that text would be processed, links(possibly) added to some words, and then reinserted back into the original markup.

Comment: Also, just in anticipation of a possible response, any text that is already linked will not have a new link added to it.

Comment: I think I understand. python has a readline() function that you could use in a for loop, then you could use if statements to determine if it found a tag and add the loop # to a list so it knows where to look for the tag. Try using regular expressions. Is that more helpful?

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it will work. It's not as elegant as I had hoped, but it answers my question. Thanks!